# "An advantage given a handicapped person at the beginning of a competition to make them draw even"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I'm looking for a single-word or set-phrase defining the advantage given a handicapped person at a competition.  I know that most competitions, including the Olympic Games, don't do that as they have a special edition for the disabled.  But some competitions, not necessarily sports, still do it.

Comment: Errm, you mean *[handicapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping)*? See e.g. *[chess handicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_handicap)*.

Comment: Obviously *handicap* is what you want here, but I'll mention [**positive discrimination**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/positive-discrimination): "the ​act of giving ​advantage to those ​groups in ​society that are often ​treated unfairly because of ​their ​race, ​sex, etc." (- Cambridge)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the term is ***[handicap](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/handicap)***: (Individual Sports, other than specified).

> - a contest, esp a race, in which competitors are given advantages or disadvantages of weight, distance, time, etc, in an attempt to equalize their chances of winning
> - ***the advantage or disadvantage prescribed.***

Collins

Comment: @ab2 - And why would it be any different for a handicapped person?  The advantage given is based on the presumed capabilities of the individual vs the "average" individual, based either on estimated differences or differences from prior performances.

Comment: Are the disabled, challenged, handicapped given a handicap based on their disability? I am asking because I don't know, not because I want to nit-pick. I am familiar with a "handicap" being given based on a person's past performance, as in golf or court tennis. As the person improves, the handicap increases.

Answer (score 5):

In late 18th-century racing, fast horses were laden with weights, to make races more even, and therefore more attractive for wagering.  The practice was called [*handicapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_race), from a 17th Century lottery game named [*hand-in-cap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-in-cap), where the name of the winning player was literally pulled from a cap.

Handicapping, giving a strong player a disadvantage so as to make sports more competitive, spread to other sports, notably golf, but also go, chess, croquet, bowling, and polo.  A match in which handicapping was used was called a *handicap* and that word began to refer to the disadvantage itself.

In the mid-20th century, as part of the ongoing [euphemism treadmill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Evolution) about human physical and intellectual disabilities, "handicap" was adopted as the catch-all word for such disabilities.

Given this history, it is ironic that “an advantage given a handicapped person” is giving his opponent a handicap.

Comment: I would call it apropos rather than ironic.  One person is handicapped already so you give a handicap to the other person to make thinks equal.

Answer (score 1):

You could say they were given a [head start](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/head+start).

> 1. an advantage given or acquired in any competition, endeavor, etc., as allowing one or more competitors in a race to start before the
>      others.